# In VS Code, can run pytest tests from terminal but not Test Explorer

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

When using VS Code, I am able to run pytest from the terminal (using `pytest` or `py.test`) from within my virtual environment (.venv). However, when I try to run the tests using the Test Explorer, it is not able to discover any tests.

I get the error: pytest discovery failed (exit code 2) and it references a logging error I/O operation on a closed file in ""C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tempfile.py". I'm confused since 1) it seems to be referencing a Python file in my system that is not in my virtual environment and 2) everything runs just fine from the VS Code terminal.

After looking at the Python output, the code that triggers the error is actually this:

```
python "C:\Users\{USERNAME}\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py" discover pytest
```

I've tried editing my settings.json to include

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestPath": "C:/Users/{...}/.venv/scripts/pytest",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:/Users/{...}/.venv/scripts/python.exe",
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "--rootdir=C:/Users/{...}/tests/",
        "--no-cov",
    ],
}
```

but nothing seems to help. What am I missing?

I am using Python 3.10.5 (same for my venv and system python) and VSCode 1.71.1.

Comment: Can [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_test-discovery) help?

Comment: I've been through the docs, to no avail. I've found that adding the "Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code  v0.7.1" extension works, but the initial "Test Explorer" in VS Code does not work.